# jOOQ and PostgreSQL domain: mapping to specific object type

Tags: postgresql, jooq, sql-domain

I'm doing some tests using PostgreSQL 9.5 and jOOQ 3.8.4.

Specifically, I want to create a domain like the following:

```
CREATE DOMAIN my_something NUMERIC(4,2);
```

then I want to create a type as follows:

```
CREATE TYPE my_type (
  something my_something;      
);
```

and finally, I have a table that has a the type as a field, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE (
  id bigserial;
  type my_type;
);
```

I see that jOOQ 3.8.4 generates the mapping of the field `something` as `Object` (both int the table record and in the POJO). I was expecting `BigDecimal` since the domain uses a `NUMERIC`.

Am I wrong? If not, is there any way to overcome the issue?

Maybe I could use `customTypes` and `forcedTypes` to register a converter, but I'm not sure it works with user defined types! Any experience on this side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL (or any other database's) data type domains are not yet fully supported in jOOQ 3.8. This is a pending feature request:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/681

In the meantime, indeed you should use a `forcedType` here to rewrite `my_type.something` to `NUMERIC`. More info here:
http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/data-type-rewrites

That's the easiest way. You could of course also write your own data type binding for a more complete solution, but I think it isn't necessary in this case. More info about data type bindings here:
http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings

Comment: @RobertoTrunfio: Glad to hear that. Did you know, on Stack Overflow, you can also answer your own question (e.g. instead of putting a partial answer in your question)

Comment: I know, I did it in the past. I actually do not like to do that when I just formalize another's answer. I feel like a thief. Another option was to enrich your answer, which I also do not like so much when it comes to major changes

Comment: @RobertoTrunfio: Why do you feel like a thief? :) You're adding value to the next visitor...

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by [Lukas Eder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/521799/lukas-eder), I just added

```
<forcedType>
  <name>NUMERIC(4,2)</name>
  <expression>my_type.something</expression>
  <types>.*</types>
</forcedType>
```

and worked very well.